# Github actions getting 403 with AWS Serverless

Tags: github-actions, serverless, aws-serverless

I tried to deploy a simple express app using github actions to aws serverless. Tried creating a new user on IAM.

[image]

Also sharing the user group and permission, i want to have a programmatic user, using which i can deploy my app directly from github.

[image]

Comment: The user from the pipeline is called `finance-manager-user`. Is that user a part of the group you mention? Also, the group is lacking permissions for API Gateway, which is what the error says as well.

Comment: i think i have missed the API Gateway permission, thanks for quick response. It worked

Answer (score 1):

##### If you want to deploy your serverless app to AWS using GitHub Actions, here are the steps to follow:

1. Create an IAM user
2. The credentials of the above user (Key ID and Key Secret) can be downloaded as a `.csv` file after you create the user.
3. Add the credentials as GitHub secrets (so that they can used in your GitHub Actions) under your repository Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions.
   Use the keys as `SLS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `SLS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET`.

[image]

4. Update your GitHub Actions `yml` file to use these credentials.

```
- name: Configure AWS Credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.SLS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.SLS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    aws-region: <specify your aws region>
- name: Deploying to ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

Now, you shall be deploying your serverless app using the above created IAM user!

---

You shall have to deploy a couple of times to figure out the actual permissions to grant to your IAM user so that it can deploy your serverless app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Role instead of user credentials as a good practice.
Its not complex as well.

The detailed steps are published here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-iam-roles-to-connect-github-actions-to-actions-in-aws/

You define OIDC provider in AWS, define a role with required permissions, add your GitHub repo in the trusted relation, so it can assume that AWS role.

Now use following action in the GitHub workflow.

```
  - name: configure aws credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.7.0
    with:
      role-to-assume: <arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/GitHubAction-AssumeRoleWithAction> #change to reflect your IAM role’s ARN
      role-session-name: GitHub_to_AWS_via_FederatedOIDC
      aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
```